# Symmetric square and tensor product.

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

## The question is:

Given a symmetric square (subspace of $V \otimes V$ such that $S^2V = \{x \in V \otimes V\ |\ \tau(x) = x \}$, where $\tau(v_1 \otimes v_2) = v_2 \otimes v_1$). Prove that for every non zero $x \in V \otimes V$ span of $\{(\phi \otimes \phi)(x)\ |\ \phi \in \mathrm{Hom}(V,V)\}$ is equal to $S^2V$

### My idea is:

Show that if $x \in S^2V$, than $(\phi \otimes \phi)(x) \in S^2V$. And than somehow show that we can make enough linearly independent vectors with different maps from any nonzero vector $x$ to form a basis of $S^2V$. But my question is how to proof this formally?

Comment: Did you mean "is equal to $S^2V$"?

Comment: Yes,it's a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** In the case that $x = y \otimes y$, we have
$$
v \otimes w = \frac 12 [(v + w)\otimes (v+w) - v \otimes v - w \otimes w]
$$
Thus, it suffices to note that there exist maps $\phi_v,\phi_w$ with $\phi_v(y) = v$ and $\phi_w(y) = w$ for any $v,w \in V$.

---

Consider the case in which $x = y \otimes z + z \otimes y$, where $y,z$ are linearly independent.  If $v,w$ are linearly independent, then there is a $\phi$ with $\phi(y) = v$ and $\phi(z) = w$.  We may also find a $\phi$ so that $\phi(y) = \phi(z) = v$, which leads to $(\phi\otimes \phi)(x) = 2(v \otimes v)$.

Comment: What is $x$ in your notation, is it the element of $V$? I'm a bit confused, because $x$ in my notation is tensor

Comment: @puhsu oh, I wasn't paying attention!  I thought you were looking at $(\phi \otimes \phi)(x \otimes x)$ for a fixed $x \in V$.

Comment: Is there a similar way to get $v \otimes w$ when $x = v_1 \otimes v_2$, where $v_1 \ne v_2$?

Comment: There must be... I'll add something if I think of it.

Comment: See my latest edit